# Photoshop: how to apply same processing to multiple photos

Tags: photoshop

I want to make a processing in Photoshop involging duplicating layers, creating new layer and applying some effects.

It is possible to store this processing as something like a macro, retrieve it and apply it to multiple images?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  You want to use an Action.  The actions palette has a recording function, just like a macro.

To apply to multiple images you can then use File > Automate > Batch, select your action and a group of images to process.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUQerO8ZX84

Comment: thats a tutorial on how to use actions